# Set size of text area based on value from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have an ajax request which is getting some data about a drink. I have 2 fields, description and awards, which are longer text inputs. This data is requested when a Bootstrap modal is opened. Specifically:

```
$('#editBeverageModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { function here }
```

I am getting the data fine and can set it in the ajax success function with

```
$('#beverageDescription').val(data['description']);
$('#beverageAwards').val(data['awards']);
```

Immediately after, is this code, which sets the height of the textareas

```
$("#beverageDescription").css('height', $("#beverageDescription").prop('scrollHeight') + 3 + "px");
$("#beverageAwards").css('height', $("#beverageAwards").prop('scrollHeight') + 3 + "px");
```

Unfortunately, the scrollHeight is always 0 even though there is text inside. How can I get Jquery to update this value before the function ends? This code works to adjust the height when the user inputs text in a later function (after the modal is opened). Thanks in advance.

Edit: For clarity here is the ajax function:

```
$('#editBeverageModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
editBeverageId = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes

$.ajax({
    url: 'UrlHere',
    data: {
        id: editBeverageId
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        $('#beverageDescription').val(data['description']).change();
        $('#beverageAwards').val(data['awards']).change();

        $("#beverageDescription").css('height', $("#beverageDescription").prop('scrollHeight') + 3 + "px").change();
        $("#beverageAwards").css('height', $("#beverageAwards").prop('scrollHeight') + 3 + "px").change();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Set an error here
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Could you please create a snippet, that would help us see better.

Comment: @V.Sambor I have updated the question with a larger snippet. I hope it helps.